# Unable to download necessary plugins to play music, video or download applications

Tags: codecs, restricted-formats, w64codecs

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm kinda new to Linux. I was just trying to do basic stuff like playing music, video using Banshee media player, but then it ask me to search for plugins and install it. I've done that, but still doesn't work. It actually doesn't download them at all.

Whats the problem? Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open the software properties and enable universe repository 
   [image]
2. open the update manager and press check button

3.open the software center and search for ubuntu-restrcted-extras 
and press install button on it

[image]
else 
open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: This site is not made to give new users Terminal commands to execute. Next time try to explain the procedure using the GUI method.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply...I have done both options but still doesn't work. It actually doesn't download at all.. at first i thought it was my network connections but i doubt it is because i can browse the Internet without any problem.

Comment: @Eduard answer updated

Comment: @Ekiee what happens when pressing install button?

Comment: It shows a task bar for download...but it doesn't actually download. It stuck there for like more than 5min and i understand it shouldn't take that long since it only needs to download about 5B..and again its not showing the "Install" button but rather it shows "Use This Source Button" .by the way i'm using university wireless Internet, maybe it has something to do with that...but surprisingly i can browse the internet with no problem and could also download files on my windows OS.

Comment: @Ekiee updated .

Comment: I just unchecked the combo-boxes @System Settings->Software Sources->Updates..like you suggested i should do but still it doesn't complete the download also it still doesn't show "Install" button but rather it shows "Use This Source" Button...Thanks once again for trying to help me.

Comment: I mean to check the combo boxes if it is unchecked,then goto update manager

Comment: Yes, I've done it like it appears above for the second time now,,,but still doesn't work. maybe there is something wrong with the way i installed it or maybe i need to reboot first.

Answer (score 2):

Open Software Center and see if you have installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` packages.

With this you can play some audio formats such as mp3 or play dvd.

For further reference or specific topics you can see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

Comment: You can also use Java applets and play Adobe Flash content on the web with the ubuntu-restricted-extras package.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply...I have done both options but still doesn't work. It actually doesn't download at all.. at first i thought it was my network connections but i doubt it is because i can browse the Internet without any problem.